# Firefox not allowing 3rd party cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, selenium

I am writing a program with selenium that collects the 3rd party cookies or a URL. The problem is that firefox keeps blocking 3rd party cookies. Can someone tell me what user_prefs in my prefs.js file need to be altered to enable 3rd party cookies. I have already tried myself but have had no luck.

Comment: Hi Richard, you said you have tried - What in particular have you tried? Could you provide some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pref is "network.cookie.cookieBehavior"

More details about its values you can find on [mozillazine kb](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior)